# Почему не видно класс?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Вот есть ссылка

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-kotlin

в которой сказано, что если хотите разделить котлин файлы и джава файлы то добавить нужно вот это

```
android {
sourceSets {
   main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}
}
```

я добавил и создал дирекоторию

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавил тестовый класс

```
class TestDeleteIt
{
fun test(iC: Context) = Toast.makeText(iC, "TTTEEESSSTTT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

И теперь хочу использовать его из джава класса который находится в джава дириктории

пишу `new TestDeleteIt()` и он его не видит

Студия директории такой не видит  я вот что добавил  `import kotlin.TestDeleteIt;` студия говорит, что такой дириктории нет

Что сделал не так?

Comment: Перед использованием класса из другого пакета, пакет надо импортировать

Comment: @Jarvis_J так дело в том, что и пакета он такого не видит , я вот что добавил  `import kotlin.TestDeleteIt;` студия говорит, что такого пакета нет

Comment: У меня пока одно объяснение: возможно вы не туда добавили нужные строки, посмотрите

Comment: @Jarvis_S вы имеете ввиду строки гредла?

Comment: пакет должен быть объявлен в котлин файле `package mypkg;` напр. (при этом совпадение структуры пакетов со структурой каталогов не обязательно, но в смешанных проектах рекомендуется). Пакет должен быть, т.к. ява не поддерживает импорт классов из пакета по-умолчанию.

Comment: Откуда вы взяли что `kotlin` это пакет? Это просто директория с исходниками, точно так же как и `java`.

Answer (score 1):

Импорты (особенно на другом языке) часто не видятся, потому что не прошла синхронизация. 
Если используете gradle, обновите в нём все зависимости
[image: refresh-gradle]

если maven, то аналогично обновите зависимости в maven.

или, если не поможет, переимпортируйте модуль (ctrl-alt-shift-s -> modules -> + -> import module, указываете build.gradle/*.pom файл, а старый модуль удаляете)
[image: import-gradle-module]

Структура пакетов начинается внутри java и kotlin директории.

Если структура такая:

src

- main
- - java
- - - ru.stackoverflow.myapp
- - - - Main.java
- - kotlin
- - - ru.stackoverflow.myapp
- - - - SomePackage.kt
- - - ru.stackoverflow.mysuperapp
- - - - MyKotlin.kt

то в Main.java должно быть
import ru.stackoverflow.mysuperapp.MyKotlin;
а для класса SomePackage.kt прописывать импорт вообще не нужно, т.к. пакет такой же